# How can I create a shared folder from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, shared-directory

As far as I'm aware, this is done via the `net` command.

However, the help section isn't very helpful, as it only shows me the secondary options and not how to use those.

Suppose I had a folder `C:\Share_test`

How would I make it shared from the command line?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`C:\>` [`net help share`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx)

For example:

> To share a computer's `C:\Data` directory with the share name `DataShare` and include a remark, type:
>
> `net share DataShare=c:\Data /remark:"For department 123."`

Comment: Some additional information as in the other answer and using the exact sample from the question would be better

Answer (score 34):

Using the "net help share" command you will see that the syntax is as follows:

```
net share sharename=drive:path
```

For example, if I had a folder S:\Public which I wanted to share as "Public" the command would be:

```
net share Public=s:\Public
```

The above command will automatically grant "Everyone" with Read permissions only.  If you want to grant Everyone with Full Control the command would be:

```
net share Public=s:\Public /GRANT:Everyone,FULL
```

Keep in mind that NTFS permissions still apply, so even though you might have granted EVERYONE with FULL access to the share, you'll still have to check the NTFS security permissions to ensure that the right people have permission there too.

Comment: A side note about localisation: spanish user should write `/GRANT:Todos,FULL` . Change it accordingly to your language.