# uri formats are not supported for Ip address in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, networking, ip-address, filepath

In my Web.Config file I have add my IP address in file path. when i try to access all files of that folder then it gives an error uri format not supported. but if i give local file path then it works fine.

```
string pathdata = Utility.GetConfigValue("DevSubmittedStateTaxForms");
string uploadPath = Utility.GetConfigValue("DevUploadFiles");

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(pathdata);
                FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.pdf"); 

                var status = new List<Object>();
                int i = 1;
                foreach (FileInfo filename in Files)
                {
                    status.Add(new {ID = i, Name = filename.Name, URL = pathdata + filename.Name + ".pdf" });
                    i++;
                }
```

Comment: What exactly is the value in DevSubmittedStateTaxForms? Simply an IP address?

Comment: This is the value <add key="DevSubmittedStateTaxForms" value="http://192.168.249.84/CBR/SubmittedStateTaxForms/"/>
In web.Config File

Comment: \ is the path separator on Windows, not / . Have you tried `\\192.168.249.84\CBR\SubmittedStateTaxForms` ?

Comment: Yes. I have also try with this one but gives same error.

Comment: Please show us your config file. That technique should work fine - I just tested it locally. What happens if you Start -> Run `\\192.168.249.84\CBR\SubmittedStateTaxForms` https://www.anoopcnair.com/run-option-windows-10/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathdata = @"\\192.168.1.27\Temp\";

            var d = new DirectoryInfo(pathdata);
            var files = d.GetFiles("*.pdf");

            foreach (var filename in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pathdata + filename.Name + ".pdf");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does work (on my machine - that is my current IP address and a folder I have shared on my machine). Your code likely doesn't work for one of two reasons:

1. Your path is not valid (e.g. using `/` instead of `\`)
2. CBR folder is not [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537065/how-can-i-create-a-shared-folder-from-the-windows-command-line?noredirect=1)